# How to save excel columns with long numbers into csv?

Tags: excel, csv

When I want to save Excel columns with long numbers like below, the resulting csv contains numbers that are converted to scientific notation which is unusable. I want them to be saved as text. Any trick to do that?

```
28160010390002003505456159  
12160010390002003505456156  
39160010390002003505456155  
39160010390002003505456155
```

Comment: format the column as text

Comment: Prepend the values with `'`

Comment: @TimWilliams your reply helped me, Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to have those long (>15 digit) numbers in Excel, they are already formatted as text.  I suspect that the .csv file also shows them as long numbers (if you open the csv file with Notepad), but that when you open the csv file in Excel, you see them as truncated and converted to scientific notation.

If that is the case, what you need to do is IMPORT the csv file.  When you do that, the text-to-columns wizard will open, and allow you to format that column as text.  The location of the Import is different in different versions.  In Excel 2007, it is on the Data ribbon, Get External Data / From Text.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks! it works fine now. Didn't know about "From Text" button.

Comment: Glad to help. For some reason, even if numbers are surrounded by double quotes, Excel (using the File Open method) will always try to interpret the values as numbers.  The Import method is how to control that.

Comment: He said SAVE A CSV. This talks about IMPORTING.  NO.

Comment: @buildmaestro Exactly. The answer addresses the real problem encountered, not what you thought the problem was. That is why it was accepted.

Answer (score 38):

Append a TAB char (ASCII 9) at the end of a number.

Comment: This one is the best solution i've found for this issue.

Comment: If the CSV is generated from SQL, you can do it like `SELECT CONCAT(field, "\t") AS "field" FROM table`

Comment: Just picky, when the user copies the cell, they will see the TAB char.

Comment: Just picky, when the user copies the cell, they will see the TAB char.

Comment: can you explain why?

Answer (score 11):

put the number as a function like below:
="123456789123456789"

Comment: I guess this is the best solution for correct visual representation, but it can give you some headache if you gonna parse data from your csv file.

Answer (score 10):

If, as the original question seems to imply, you are actually:

1. already working with **data in Excel**, and
2. want to **save to a CSV** format without losing digits in an extra long number,

Then, before doing a 'Save As' to your CSV format, try formatting the column with a custom format, and in the box for the pattern just type `#`. This will force Excel to see it as a number, however many digits long, without trying to do something else with it like `4.52364E+14` when you actually save it to CSV.

At least, that is how it works for me in Excel 365 at this point in time.

If you are trying to get data ***into*** Excel from a CSV, then the answer about using the data import wizard is probably the safest bet instead.

Comment: Works with Excel 2013 also.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but since at the moment it's still the top result on a google search for the topic, I think the thread should be kept current.   Hussein mahyoub provided the only real answer to the question, yet has not gotten the up-votes.

The answer which tells us to add a tab character after your number gets you an string of text with a tab after it inside excel.  It looks visually correct, but, it's not correct inside the spreadsheet.   If the intent is to use the data in excel as excel data and use formula etc, it could cause problems.  Interestingly if you put the tab before the text, it shows up in the data after the text.

The answer which tells us inserting a ' before the text gets a ' in the excel file.  It's visually an incorrect representation of the data.

The answer which boasts the virtue of openoffice is simply an evil troll which does not even attempt to answer the question.

The answer that explains how to import a CSV that has not been properly formatted is good information, but, off topic.

The direct answer to the question is

```
converted to text,largest number
="123456789012",12345678901
```

Comment: I found the question trying to solve my own problem.   The specific's of the question are ambiguous.  

Since this is stackoverflow, my assumption is that the question is not en end user question trying to figure out how to use excel to output data.

As as developer, I needed to create the file manually.  If you are generating a file as a programmer, this is the best method I've found to accomplish this.
Based on my interpretation of the question, most of these answers are off topic.

Comment: This is the correct answer to question in the title IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the numeric to text using text function.

```
Text(number,"0")
```

Comment: It's not working when the number is longer then 15 digit. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/numbers-in-csv-file-longer-then-15-digit-are-lost/8d779cc3-2f16-4bda-bbd0-9c4edcf2549b

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Export to csv feature in Excel.
You can easy format that column to number in Excel, then use "Save as" it with csv and "yes" to confirm that you want to keep the format in csv.
That is work for me
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

using openoffice you can save in csv format without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the column that has scientific exponent number and go to Format cells and then Numbers (decimal point as 0), save it as MSDOS CSV. Worked for me.