# How to import long number from csv to a database without converting to scientific notation in VBA

Tags: vba, csv, scientific-notation

I have a  CSV file that I would like to import all data on it .So far I can read all the data in the file to my database but the long number I have there is converted to scientific notation  making my data redundant. When I open my CSV file in notepad ++ the data looks good in its original format but when I open the same file in excel the data is in scientific notation.The problem is I am using VBA excel to read my CSV file so the data I get is the same as when I open my file in excel.I would like to be able to use VBA excel for import but get the original number not scientific notation one is there a way to manipulate that so when I do my import I get the long number in its original format.
so far here is the code for my import

```
con.Provider = "Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0"
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & currentDataFilePath & ";" & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"""
'MsgBox currentDataFilePath

con.Open

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & currentDataFileName & "] ", con
rs.MoveFirst
'nextRow = Worksheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
'Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(nextRow, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

'MsgBox rs.RecordCount
With rs
Do Until .EOF

'check the field is not null before process

 If Not IsNull(rs("Invoice Number")) Then
 InvoiceNum = rs("Invoice Number")
 End If
    If Not IsNull(rs("Payer Name")) Then
 PayerName = rs("Payer Name")
 End If
    If Not IsNull(rs("Card Number")) Then
 CardNumber = """" & rs("Card Number") & """"
 End If
    If Not IsNull(rs("Licence Number")) Then
 LicenceNumber = rs("Licence Number")
 End If
    If Not IsNull(rs("Driver Name")) Then
 DriverName = rs("Driver Name")
 End If
    If Not IsNull(rs("Transaction Date")) Then
 TransactionDate = rs("Transaction Date")
 End If

sqlstring="INSERT INTO tabledata set InvoiceNum='"& InvoiceNum &"',PayerName='" & PayerName &"',CardNumber='" & CardNumber &"',TransactionDate='" & TransactionDate &"'"
call insertQuery(sqlstring)
.movenext
Loop
 End With
```

Comment: have you tried to change cell format to text, that way excel should not try to convert numeric valued

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  The code you posted is using a text driver.  Where does the spreadsheet come into play?

Comment: @Comintern please try and understand the question .Now the problem is when I use the above routine in vba to import my csv file the long number is imported in scientific notation.I would like to know a way to avoid or take care of this when I am doing my import through vba code which is above so far have read here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647042/how-to-save-excel-columns-with-long-numbers-into-csv] and of no help

Comment: Import into *what*? The code you posted only creates a recordset using the ADO text driver and assigns them to some random identifiers. Where exactly is it showing up in scientific notation?  In one of the variables\controls\whatever `InvoiceNum` or `LicenceNumber` is? On a worksheet somewhere?

Comment: @Comintern "CardNumber" this number is about 22 to 31 digits long I have a query that takes those variables and populate the database which is MYSQL DB that bit is fine just the manipulation of cardnumber is what i struggle with

Comment: ^^That's the code people would need to see to answer this question.

Comment: @Comintern added the SQL as per your request see if you can help please