# .csv file looses the format when the column is text type

Tags: excel

I have a text file that I need to convert to .csv format. I opened the file in Excel 2010 and made some of the columns data format as Text column with the help of text import wizard. I save the file as .csv (Comma delimited). When I opened the file again, some of the columns that I saved as Text became 1.23424E+13
 with E in it. I thought if I change the format of the column to text then E does not come in the column, but in my case E comes back when I save the file as .csv. When I save the file as .xls then it keeps that format. Is there any way, I can keep the the text format of the column in .csv file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to save excel columns with long numbers into csv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647042/how-to-save-excel-columns-with-long-numbers-into-csv)

Comment: A CSV file is already text format. It's not an Excel file. What's your actual problem? In what way do you need to transform this file?