# VBA: How to fix long numbers Scientific notation in 140 CSV files UTF-8?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, scientific-notation

I'm working on a master sheet which contains 50,000 users that belong to 140 departments. So I split them to 140 worksheets using below script#1, then I save them as separate CSV files using below script#2.

My issue is that the master sheet has one column contains Arabic names and two others columns contain long numbers > 15. So there are two scenarios:

1. When I save the files as `xlCSVUTF8`, the Arabic names are OK but Long numbers are converted in e.g. 9.71434E+14.
2. When I save the files as `xlCSVMac` the long numbers are OK (no scientific notation) but Arabic names are turned into ?????.

I have tried all the CSV formats but only UTF-8 accepts Arabic.
The Import Text wizard one-by-one solution is not effective as I have so many files.

Script#1

```vb
Sub SplitandFilterSheet()
    Dim Splitcode As Range
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Set Splitcode = Range("Splitcode")

    For Each Cell In Splitcode
        Sheets("Master").Copy after:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = Cell.Value

        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(CStr(Cell.Value)).Range("MasterData")
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & Cell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Script#2

```vb
Sub CreateNewWBS()
    Dim wbThis As Workbook
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strFilename As String

    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wbThis.Worksheets
        strFilename = wbThis.Path & "/" & ws.Name
        ws.Copy
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        wbNew.SaveAs strFilename, xlCSVUTF8
        wbNew.Close
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Is there any way to get all the CSV files fixed and have Arabic names and numbers OK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to save excel columns with long numbers into csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22647042/11683)

Comment: So, based on @GSerg 's comment, if you first convert all long numbers to text, and save as xlCSVUTF8, then you may have names and numbers both correct?

Comment: @ Andras I have tried that but it doesnt work, its atomatically converted in scientific notations when its saved as csv.

Comment: @GSerg Is there a way to do text import wizard in bulk for 140 files that have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, [there is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext). But I would rather convert the number to text.