# Incorrect String Length While Reading A CSV File Using PHP

Tags: php, csv, fopen, fgetcsv

I am reading a CSV file, line by line using following php code.

```
<?php
$temp=0;
$s="http://localhost/BulkMessage/Uploads/Number_Files/f7aa248e5fce52411723_CSV_7xxxxxxxx.csv";
try
{
    $file = fopen($s, 'r');
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $_SESSION['error']="Can't read the file";
    header('Location: '.'../view_sending_rich_message.php');
}
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)
{
    echo $line[0]." Length: ".strlen($line[0])."<br>";
}

?>
```

Reading process works as expected, but when I try to print the length of a line it shows some abnormal behavior. 
These are few sample lines from my CSV.

1. 71455169311
2. 71455169112222100

For both of these lines, the string length is shown as 11. For the first one it is correct, but second one has 16 characters. It seems that for any value which has more than 11 characters, string length is shown as 11 (When strlen is used) .
Below shows the out of my php script for above 2 lines.

```
71455169311 Length: 11
7.14552E+16 Length: 11
```

Is there any way to get the string length correctly? What is the reason for this behavior?
Thanks

Comment: Loooks like the line with the longer number is being presented to you in the format you are printing which is 11 chars

Comment: Is this Q&A any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647042/how-to-save-excel-columns-with-long-numbers-into-csv

Comment: @RiggsFolly Now, I know the reason for that behavior. I used excel to create the csv and it seems that excel is reformatting numbers a scientific format. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `fgetcsv` can return integers / floats, not only strings. If the exact numbers are required, than I don't know if `fgetcsv` can also return everything as a string, but if only the length of the string is required, you can use `strlen(number_format($line[0], 0, '.', ''))` (this is assuming the numbers have no decimals).

Comment: In my case, csv contains telephone numbers.So, there is no issue arising due to decimals. Your answer is doing the job for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: As @RiggsFolly  Suggested, following Q&A shows the reason.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647042/how-to-save-excel-columns-with-long-numbers-into-csv

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `strlen()` try using `mb_strlen()`.

Comment: I tried it. But it gives the same result as strlen(). It seems that there is nothing to with stren(), excel is reformatting numbers in  scientific notation.Thanks for your response.