# Python - Matching and extracting data from excel with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iterator

I am working on a python script that automates some phone calls for me. I have a tool to test with that I can interact with REST API. I need to select a specific carrier based on which country code is entered. So let's say my user enters 12145221414 in my excel document, I want to choose AT&T as the carrier. How would I accept input from the first column of the table and then output what's in the 2nd column?

Obviously this can get a little tricky, since I would need to match up to 3-4 digits on the front of a phone number. My plan is to write a function that then takes the initial number and then plugs the carrier that needs to be used for that country.

Any idea how I could extract this data from the table? How would I make it so that if you entered Barbados (1246), then Lime is selected instead of AT&T?

Here's my code thus far and tables. I'm not sure how I can read one table and then pull data from that table to use for my matching function.

**testlist.xlsx**

```
| Number |
|:------------|
|8155555555|
|12465555555|
|12135555555|
|96655555555|
|525555555555|
```

**carriers.xlsx**

```
| countryCode | Carrier |
|:------------|:--------|
|1246|LIME|
|1|AT&T|
|81|Softbank|
|52|Telmex|
|966|Zain|
```

```
import pandas as pd
import os

FILE_PATH = "C:/temp/testlist.xlsx"
xl_1 = pd.ExcelFile(FILE_PATH)
num_df = xl_1.parse('Numbers')

FILE_PATH = "C:/temp/carriers.xlsx"
xl_2 = pd.ExcelFile(FILE_PATH)
car_df = xl_2.parse('Carriers')


for index, row in num_df.iterrows():
```

Comment: if possible, try to work with CSV. CSV is open-source and is compatible with excel too. XLSX is proprietary and has limited support.

Comment: The problem with using CSV is that it isn't compressed, like XLS or XLSX files, thus resulting to exponentially larger files. Not to mention the problem with handling huge numbers when saving in CSV format as in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647042/how-to-save-excel-columns-with-long-numbers-into-csv/22649446 Well it's case to case basis, if it fits your case :)

Comment: In other words, do you want to find the longest prefix from the second table that is contained in your number?

Comment: Can you check it [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68588044/16343464) using a regex matches you need? It should be relatively fast as only the first match is used.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea how I could extract this data from the table? How would I
> make it so that if you entered Barbados (1246), then Lime is selected
> instead of AT&T?

**carriers.xlsx**

| countryCode | Carrier |
| --- | --- |
| 1246 | LIME |
| 1 | AT&T |
| 81 | Softbank |
| 52 | Telmex |
| 966 | Zain |

**script.py**

```
import pandas as pd

FILE_PATH = "./carriers.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(FILE_PATH)
rows_list = df.to_dict('records')
code_carrier_map = {}

for row in rows_list:
    code_carrier_map[row["countryCode"]] = row["Carrier"]

print(type(code_carrier_map), code_carrier_map)

print(f"{code_carrier_map.get(1)=}")
print(f"{code_carrier_map.get(1246)=}")
print(f"{code_carrier_map.get(52)=}")
print(f"{code_carrier_map.get(81)=}")
print(f"{code_carrier_map.get(966)=}")
```

**Output**

```
$ python3 script.py 
<class 'dict'> {1246: 'LIME', 1: 'AT&T', 81: 'Softbank', 52: 'Telmex', 966: 'Zain'}
code_carrier_map.get(1)='AT&T'
code_carrier_map.get(1246)='LIME'
code_carrier_map.get(52)='Telmex'
code_carrier_map.get(81)='Softbank'
code_carrier_map.get(966)='Zain'
```

---

Then if you want to parse phone numbers, don't reinvent the wheel, just use this [phonenumbers](https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/) library.

**Code**

```
import phonenumbers

num = "+12145221414"
phone_number = phonenumbers.parse(num)
print(f"{num=}")
print(f"{phone_number.country_code=}")
print(f"{code_carrier_map.get(phone_number.country_code)=}")
```

**Output**

```
num='+12145221414'
phone_number.country_code=1
code_carrier_map.get(phone_number.country_code)='AT&T'
```

Comment: This is super helpful! I've mostly built selenium scripts that are procedural and I'm trying to break out of my shell. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm mostly just surprised I didn't know that there's a phone numbers module.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the following input:

```
>>> df1
         Number
0    8155555555
1   12465555555
2   12135555555
3   96655555555
4  525555555555

>>> df2
   countryCode   Carrier
0         1246      LIME
1            1      AT&T
2           81  Softbank
3           52    Telmex
4          966      Zain
```

First we need to rework a bit df2 to sort the `countryCode` in descending order, make it as string and set it to index.

**The trick for later is to sort `countryCode` in descending order. This will ensure that a longer country codes, such as "1246" is matched before a shorter one like "1".**

```
>>> df2 = df2.sort_values(by='countryCode', ascending=False).astype(str).set_index('countryCode')
>>> df2
              Carrier
countryCode          
1246             LIME
966              Zain
81           Softbank
52             Telmex
1                AT&T
```

Finally, we use a regex (here `'1246|966|81|52|1'` using `'|'.join(df2.index)`) made from the country codes in descending order to extract the longest code, and we map it to the carrier:

```
(df1.astype(str)['Number']
    .str.extract('^(%s)'%'|'.join(df2.index))[0]
    .map(df2['Carrier'])
)
```

output:

```
0    Softbank
1        LIME
2        AT&T
3        Zain
4      Telmex
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

NB. to add it to the initial dataframe:

```
df1['carrier'] = (df1.astype(str)['Number']
                     .str.extract('^(%s)'%'|'.join(df2.index))[0]
                     .map(df2['Carrier'])
                 ).to_clipboard(0)
```

output:

```
         Number   carrier
0    8155555555  Softbank
1   12465555555      LIME
2   12135555555      AT&T
3   96655555555      Zain
4  525555555555    Telmex
```

Comment: A combination of this solution and Niel's solution below will help me get this done! Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want to provide this combination for the community? ;)

Comment: I certainly will, Mozway. As soon as I iron it out..

Answer (score 0):

I can think only of an inefficient solution.

First, sort the data frame of carriers in the reverse alphabetical order of country codes. That way, longer prefixes will be closer to the beginning.

```
codes = xl_2.sort_values('countryCode', ascending=False)
```

Next, define a function that matches a number with each country code in the second data frame and finds the index of the first match, if any (remember, that match is the longest).

```
def cc2carrier(num):
    matches = codes['countryCode'].apply(lambda x: num.startswith(x))
    if not matches.any(): #Not found
        return np.nan
    return codes.loc[matches.idxmax()]['Carrier']
```

Now, apply the function to the numbers dataframe:

```
xl_1['Number'].apply(cc2carrier)
#1    Softbank
#2        LIME
#3        AT&T
#4        Zain
#5      Telmex
#Name: Number, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you just want to get the first characters from the input column (Number) and then match this with the second dataframe from carriers.xlsx.

Extract first characters of a Number column. Hint: The nbr_of_chars variable should be based on the maximum character length of the column countryCode in the carriers.xlsx

```
nbr_of_chars = 4
df.loc[df['Number'].notnull(), 'FirstCharsColumn'] = df['Number'].str[:nbr_of_chars]
```

Then the matching should be fairly easy with dataframe joins.